# How does SCIP choose which branching rule to use?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, scip, sat

My datasets consist of large SAT instances. I am trying to find out how SCIP's default settings selects the branching rule to use.

There is a dataset that I have which consists of 7295 variables and 409834 constraints. After setting the time limit for 8h, using default settings and writing the statistics into a file, I see that SCIP has called `inference` branching.

However, when I tried this again with a smaller data set of 1040 variables and 3668 constraints, SCIP called `relpscost` branching instead.

Is there some documentation or code to what criterion SCIP uses to select the branching rule? I am currently unable to find it if that exists.

Comment: I would also ask you to please accept the answers on your question, if you are satisified with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained in detail in the documentation of branching rules, so I will just post a link here (section priority):

https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/BRANCH.php